# Scala program fails when calling apply method of custom object, but doesn't fail when call method that apply later calls

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a custom object that behaves the same as the "while" control structure, so i defined an object Whilst, with recursive methods that allows the behavior of "while" to be implemented.
The apply method of my object calls a recursive helper method. The problem is that if i call this helper method directly it works, but when i call apply method it iterates the first time then it kinda gets stucked in that iteration.

```
object Whilst {

 def apply(condition:Boolean)(codeBlock:Unit):Unit = whilst(condition)(codeBlock)

      def whilst(testCondition: => Boolean)(codeBlock: => Unit):Unit = {
        if (testCondition) {
          codeBlock
          whilst(testCondition)(codeBlock)
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing about the apply method?
When i run my program like this there is no problem.
var a = 1

```
Whilst.whilst(a < 5) {
  println(a)
  a = a + 1
}
```

Then i call like this, and the problem mentioned above appears.

```
Whilst(a < 5) {
      println(a)
      a = a + 1
    }
```

Comment: You need to make `condition` a **_by-name_** parameter in `apply` too. Right now, you have an infinite loop, because it will evaluate to false the first time, and always will. The same goes to the `block` - `def apply(condition: => Boolean)(codeBlock: => Unit): Unit = whilst(condition)(codeBlock)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is caused by both `testCondition` and `codeBlock` of the `whilst` method being evaluated eagerly and only once. In order for this to work, these code blocks need to be evaluated on every iteration.

You have to change the signature of `whilst` as follows:

```
def whilst(testCondition: => Boolean)(codeBlock: => Unit):Unit
```

This `value: => Type` is called a by-name value and is eveluated every time its used.